# hidesBackButton works but backbarbuttonitem setAction not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, backbarbuttonitem

I'd like to change action of my backbutton in one of my ViewController. Instead of going back to the precedent view, I want to perform an action in the same ViewController.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=NO;
```

hides the BackButton but

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(performBackNav:)];
```

and

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(performBackNav:)];
```

do the same as before (going back to precedent ViewController). Nothing changes.

```
-(void)performBackNav:(id)sender {
//Actions
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Any ideas to modify backbarbuttonitem's action ?

Comment: Have you verified whether or not `performBackNav:` is even being called via a breakpoint or NSLog statement?

Comment: Yep. performBackNav: is not called (NSLog statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding the action method of default back button create a custom button. this is one of the way Try this

```
{
    UIButton *urButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    urButton.frame = urRequiredFrame;
    [urButton setImage:urImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [urButton addTarget:self action:@selector(performBackNav:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:urButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=doneButton;
}


-(void)performBackNav:(id)sender {
//Actions
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```